# Здравствуйте! Питон.Не могу открыть csv. словарь

Tags: python, csv, словарь

Есть цикл, который рандомно генерирует имена и номера телефонов и записывает их в csv.файл.
Теперь когда я хочу прочитать его и найти имя, или номер телефона выходит keyerror.

```
Username = {"Vasya":123456, "Sasha": 342154}
print(Username["Vasya"])
```

123456, а должно быть так.

При том, что если я пишу словарь вручную, т.е сам добавляю имена все работает

```
from ast import NameConstant
import random
import names

    f=open(r"C:\расположение файла\name.csv","r+")
    name_phone = {}
    for i in range(5):
        user_n = names.get_full_name()
        phone_num = str(random.randint(1000000,9999999))
        user_p = '054-'+phone_num
        name_phone.update({user_n: user_p})
        record = ','.join([user_n,user_p])
        f.write(record + '\n')
f.close()
```

пробую читать так

```
    print(name_phone['сгенерированое имя'])
    keyerror
```

или так:

```
    namel = []
       lines = f.readlines()
       for i in lines():
           a = i.strip('\n')
           pair = a.split(',')
           namel.append(pair[0], pair[1])
    print(namel)
```

ничего не выходит

Comment: Как читаете? Приведите, пожалуйста, этот код в вопрос

Comment: Исправил, добавил код

Comment: Какие-то обрывки кода, которые непонятно как вместе соединены... ``print(namel)`` что-то да должно вывести. Что выводит?

Comment: Вы генерируете словарь, а потом читаете его из файла не как словарь, а как список. У вас какая-то путаница вообще. Вы разберитесь по частям: 1) правильно ли генерируются данные? 2) правильно ли пишутся в файл? 3) правильно ли читаются из файла? И задавайте вопрос именно по тому этапу, который работает неправильно. Если это чтение файла, то вопрос должен быть такой: есть файл такого-то формата, читаю, пытаясь получить такую-то структуру данных, получается не то, что нужно. Остальные части вашего вопроса тогда лишние (генерация и запись в файл). Вы определитесь, лишнего не нужно писать в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это именно то, что имелось ввиду, но можно использовать пандас для работы с csv файлами. Чтобы прочитать файл используй pd.read_csv(тут путь к файлу). Например:

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'Name': ['Ivan', 'Kolya'], 'Cell': [123, 456]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df[df['Name']=='Ivan']['Cell'].values[0])
```

Вывод:
123